# Duplicate a div containing functioning elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I've a draggable box with an append button to fill the box with elements.
I would like to have a button wich duplicates this box with all of its functions and elements.

my problem and question at the moment is;
how can i duplicate the whole box? Including its elements and functions?

Here is  a preview of the code;

http://jsfiddle.net/AttEb/

Comment: What do you mean with functions? Event handlers?

Comment: well there is an append function a remove function an input function and i want all those functions to be in the clone too :)

Comment: I had a look at your code.... don't use IDs on element you want to clone. Use classes instead. And `append` just adds another element to an element. If you clone the parent, you clone the child too. You don't need to append again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method, but pass `true` as the argument.

From the documentation:

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements...
>
> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well...

Note that if you have set up event handlers using `live` and/or `delegate`, those will automatically affect the new elements as well, as long as they match the same selectors.